# PHP - Ignore NULL in SQL Select Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull a list of my actors via the foreign key stored in my main 'movies' table.  It will work if all actor fields are populated, but will die if any one of those fields are NULL.

```
$stars = mysql_query("
    SELECT actor_name
    FROM actors
    WHERE actorID = $row[5] OR actorID = $row[6] OR actorID = $row[7] OR actorID = $row[8]  OR actorID = $row[9] OR actorID = $row[10]
")
or die("<h1>Error - (stars) the query could not be executed</h1>\n");
$count = 0;
while ($row_stars = mysql_fetch_array($stars)) {
    print("$row_stars[0]<br/>\n");
    if ($count == 2) {
        print("</td>\n");
        print("<td>\n");
    }
    $count++;
}
print("</td>\n </tr>\n");
```

Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why are you using this? Why can't you use INNER JOIN?

Comment: instead of all those ORs use the IN command. like this actorID IN ($row[5],...)

Comment: And also escape and quote your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$actors = array_slice($row, 2, 6);
$actors_without_nulls = array_filter($actors, 'strlen');
$actorIds = implode(', ', $actors_without_nulls);
```

Now try,

```
SELECT actor_name
FROM actors
WHERE actorID IN ( actorIds )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The array slice is selecting the wrong values from my array.  Should it not be ($row, 5, 6) i.e  starting at the 5th element and return 6 values? Even when I run this, it returns the wrong element, but if I print out $row[5] it is the correct element.

Comment: So i've got the slice working now, needs to be ($row, 10, 12).
My code is as follows:
`$actors = array_slice($row, 10, 12);          $actors_without_nulls = array_filter($actors, 'strlen');        $actorIds = implode(', ', $actors_without_nulls);        $stars = mysql_query("SELECT actor_name FROM actors WHERE actorID IN ( $actorIds )")          or die("<h1>Error - (stars) the query could not be executed</h1>\n");`

This will still not work for NULL Values.

Comment: The array indexes were wrong... I tried it locally using a test array, and copied that on to the response. So many variables are declared to make it easier to understand. You can chain them together.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MySQL COALESCE() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)

```
$stars = mysql_query("
    SELECT actor_name
    FROM actors
    WHERE actorID = COALESCE($row[5],$row[6],$row[7],$row[8],$row[9],$row[10],-1)
")
```